# Problem with setting a direction for multiple entitys in a java game

Tags: java, entity

I wan't to give all of my gost entities a random direction, but I can't figure out how

I've managed to set all of my entities Direction to either move in X or in Y steps, but it's a static movement, is there anyway to move them randomly? maybe by using a timer of some sort?

```
    private GameScreen gs;

    private boolean gameRunning = true;
    private int fps;

    private Entity player;

    private ArrayList<Entity> entityList = new ArrayList<>();

    private HashMap<String, Boolean> keyDown = new HashMap<>();

        public void loadObjects() {
        Image playerImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/playerImg.png")).getImage();
        Image gostImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/gostImg.png")).getImage();

        player = new Entity(playerImg, 100, 200, 200);

        entityList.add(player);
        entityList.add(new Entity(gostImg, 224, 350, 60));
        entityList.add(new Entity(gostImg, 460, 250, 60));
        entityList.add(new Entity(gostImg, 624, 300, 60));
        entityList.add(new Entity(gostImg, 942, 550, 60));
        entityList.add(new Entity(gostImg, 520, 560, 60));
    }

    public void update(long deltaTime) {
        checkCollisionandRemove();

        if(keyDown.get("right")) {
            player.setDirectionX(1);
            player.setDirectionY(0);
        }
        else if(keyDown.get("left")){
            player.setDirectionX(-1);
            player.setDirectionY(0);
        }

        if(keyDown.get("up")) {
            player.setDirectionY(-1);
            player.setDirectionX(0);
        }
        else if(keyDown.get("down")) {
            player.setDirectionY(1);
            player.setDirectionX(0);
        }

        if(player.getX() < 0) {
            player.setX(0);
        }

        if(player.getX() > gs.getWidth() -  player.getWidth()) {
            player.setX(gs.getWidth() -  player.getWidth());
        }

        if(player.getY() < 0) {
            player.setY(0);
        }

        if(player.getY() > gs.getHeight() -  player.getHeight()) {
            player.setY(gs.getHeight() -  player.getHeight());
        }

        for(Entity entity : entityList) {
            entity.moveX(deltaTime);
            entity.moveY(deltaTime);
            entity.setDirectionX(1);

            if(entity.equals(player)) {
                player.setDirectionX(0);
                player.setDirectionY(0);
            }

            if(entity.getX() < 0){
                entity.setX(0);
            }

            if(entity.getX() > gs.getWidth() - entity.getWidth()) {
                entity.setX(gs.getWidth() - entity.getWidth());
            }

            if(entity.getY() < 0) {
                entity.setY(0);
            }

            if(entity.getY() > gs.getHeight() - entity.getHeight()) {
                entity.setY(gs.getHeight() - player.getHeight());
            }
        }

        player.moveX(deltaTime);
        player.moveY(deltaTime);

    }
```

I wan't my entities to have a random direction instead of one static.

Comment: There's a lot of problems here.  You're adding "gost" to a list, but only moving the last "gost".  You need to loop through your list of entities.  And where are you setting the direction?

Comment: As  @SteveSmith said, there are missing some parts of the program. There is no iteration-loop right now where you access all ghosts. We need some more code-segments to help you.

Comment: I'm setting my direction in the update function but I removed it since it only set on of the gosts direction. I don't think I'm quite sure what you mean by iteration-loop

Comment: @L.Isen You only move the player and the last ghost you create.  If you want to move all the ghosts, you need to iterate through your `entityList` and move *everything* in the list.  That'll move the player and all of the ghosts.

Comment: @Jordan I don't want to move the player aswell, I only want to move the "gost" entities, since the player will be able to use the arrow keys to move. Yeah but I'm having problem with how I iterate through my list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a few problems. The first being that you have a single "gost" object defined as a global variable. Then you set it's value multiple times and add it to an ArrayList. My assumption is that your list only has one gost in it.

Here is your code with a few modifications. I didn't test any of this, but give it a try.

```
private GameScreen gs;

private boolean gameRunning = true;
private int fps;

private Entity player;

//private Entity gost; Removed because I don't think you need this. 

private ArrayList<Entity> entityList = new ArrayList<>();

private HashMap<String, Boolean> keyDown = new HashMap<>();

public void loadObjects() {
    Image playerImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/playerImg.png")).getImage();
    Image gostImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/gostImg.png")).getImage();

    player = new Entity(playerImg, 100, 200, 200);
    //entityList.add(player); I don't think you need this either, unless you check all of your entities in your checkCollisionandRemove() method

    //Create your "Gost" entities this way.
    entityList.add(new Entity(gostImg, 224, 350, 10));
    entityList.add(new Entity(gostImg, 460, 20, 10));
    entityList.add(new Entity(gostImg, 624, 300, 10));
    entityList.add(new Entity(gostImg, 942, 550, 20));
    entityList.add(new Entity(gostImg, 520, 760, 30));
}
public void update(long deltaTime) {
    checkCollisionandRemove();

    if(keyDown.get("right")) {
        player.setDirectionX(1);
        player.setDirectionY(0);
    }
    else if(keyDown.get("left")){
        player.setDirectionX(-1);
        player.setDirectionY(0);
    }

    if(keyDown.get("up")) {
        player.setDirectionY(-1);
        player.setDirectionX(0);
    }
    else if(keyDown.get("down")) {
        player.setDirectionY(1);
        player.setDirectionX(0);
    }

    if(player.getX() < 0) {
        player.setX(0);
    }

    if(player.getX() > gs.getWidth() -  player.getWidth()) {
        player.setX(gs.getWidth() -  player.getWidth());
    }

    if(player.getY() < 0) {
        player.setY(0);
    }

    if(player.getY() > gs.getHeight() -  player.getHeight()) {
        player.setY(gs.getHeight() -  player.getHeight());
    }

    player.moveX(deltaTime);
    player.moveY(deltaTime);

    //Move each gost this way.
    for(Entity entity : entityList) {   
        /*
            If you need to include your player object into the entity list you will need a way to tell whether entity is a gost or player.
            Something like: if(entity.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("gost")) then move
        */

        entity.moveX(deltaTime);
        entity.moveY(deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's how I used to have it before I changed it, but I just get "entity can't be resolved" so I can't use "entity.moveX(deltaTime); since it just gets red marked

Comment: fixed it! just had to move the entity.moveX(deltaTime); in the for-loop, thanks for the help :)

Comment: But is there anyway to give them a random direction? without having to press an arrow key or something like that?

Comment: Yeah, you could make them move randomly by generating a random number and passing it into you moveX/Y methods. However, then your gost would appear to jump from place to place. Ie: if they are x:1 y:1 on the first move, then the next time they update they might be x:7 y:5. So in order to make their movement more fluid you might want to consider have some kind of destination coordinates (generated with the random number) and then only generate a new destination once they have reached the previous one. Also, if you don't mind marking my answer the correct one that would be great.